# How to maintain fix image size whilst still being responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS (using Bootstrap) to resize an image to fit inside a 16:9 container without stretching:

```
<span class="bg-dark d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center style="width: 384px; 
height: 216px">
                <img
                  :src="slotProps.item.itemImageSrc"
                  :alt="slotProps.item.alt"
                  style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%"
                />
              </span>
```

This works, however when I use it inside Bootstrap grid, the image overflows the grid (I think because I am fixing the size with an absolute value. How do I make it so that the image is resized, but does not overflow?

(context: this is used inside a gallery component, the images coming in ay be different sizes so I need to resize them all to so that they display inside the same size container with black bars either at the top or bottom)

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio